# Data inserted into a database manually won't show up in Spring Boot repository

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa, h2

I added a bunch of test data to a table in my H2 database but when I search for it with my JPA repository, it cannot find it (with a `findById`). Does Spring Boot/JPA always "ingest" the newly added data in an SQL database ? Just want to be certain of this so I don't waste time on it.

Comment: Is your H2 database persistent or in-memory only?

Comment: it is persistent

Comment: I'm getting a 'no value present' error when searching a repository with `findById`, but the data is in the table... I tried specifying the query manually with `@Query` but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Maybe your Spring Boot app is connecting to a different instance of H2 compared to the one tool you are using to view the data. It happened to me long back when running H2 inside the SpringBoot instance. For testing purposes I decided to run H2 outside Spring Boot so I could simultaneously connect from the app and also from an external tool (Squirrel SQL client) to verify the data. That solved my problem.